# alpine js how to total x-for items

Tags: sum, alpine.js

thought this was going to be pretty simple but how could i iterate through template x-for items -doing a sum calculation to output at the end.. [or even if i already have the total in the sourcedata - how to output as the last row? i.e how to x-if last row ]

e.g.

```
 <template x-for="catalogxbdata in catalogxbdatax" :key="catalogxbdata.Part">
      <div class="table-row">
          <Div class="table-cell"></div>
          <Div class="table-cell" x-text="catalogxbdata.Price"></div>    
          <Div class="table-cell" x-text="?total here"></div> <--- but only if last row
     </Div>
    </template>
    <Div class="table-cell"> </div>
    <Div class="table-cell" x-text="?total here"></div> <-- or here, but this is outside of template
```

Answer (score 0):

posting the answers in case someone has the same ..

```
<script>
function setVals() {

  return {
    total_c1:0,
    total_c2:0,
    settotalifindata(valx)
    {
    this.total_c1=valx;
    },
    //or
    settotal(valx)
    {
    this.totalc2+=valx;
    }
}
}
</script>

<div id="a0" class="p-1" x-data="setVals()">

<template x-for="catalogxbdata in catalogxbdatax" :key="catalogxbdata.Part">
      <div class="table-row">
          <Div class="table-cell"></div>
          <Div class="table-cell" x-text="catalogxbdata.Price"></div> 
          <div class="table-cell" x-show="false" x-text="settotalifindata(catalogxbdata.total)"></div>   
          <div class="table-cell" x-show="false" x-text="settotal(catalogxbdata.Price)"></div>   

          <Div class="table-cell" x-text="total_c1"></div> <--- but only if last row
     </Div>
    </template>
    <Div class="table-cell"> </div>
    <Div class="table-cell" x-text="total_c2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is that going to run? There is not even a `catalogxbdatax` array defined anywhere in the component, the `settotalifindata()` function is undefined, and also the `settotal(valx)`... please post complete code examples in your questions/answers or don't post them at all.

Answer (score 0):

I also work like this! But functions settotal was undefined!
So, I fix the issue. The issue was version of alpinejs.

https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js
Hopefully your problem will be solve!